# C# Data Structure Similar to A Thread(Storing method calls)

Tags: c#, multithreading, data-structures

I am writing a simulation program and I'm looking for a way to store a list of method calls similar to how a Thread functions(Thread.add(Object.Method)). I then want to remove these method calls and add them to thread objects. Is there any built in data structure in C# that does this? Or is there a way for me to make one that does what I want.

Comment: you can hold a list of `Action<T>` delegate. `List<Action<t>> list = new List<Action<T>>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to store a list of method calls

You could create a list of delegates (references to methods), like this:

```
public delegate void DoSomething();

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<DoSomething> actions = new List<DoSomething>();
        actions.Add(TestMethod);
        actions.Add(delegate {
           // Anonymous Method 1
        });
        actions.Add(delegate {
            // Anonymous Method 2
        });
    }

    static void TestMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Note that you don't really need to define new delegate as there is `Action`, `Action<...>` and many of the `Func<...>` that usually take care of such delegates.